# Best way to fill an image placed into a larger box without creating artificial edges?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

If you are training a neural net for a bunch of images of different size, and you have to put them all in a same-size enclosing box for input to the neural net, what's the best way to fill the background, if at all, where the inserted image is not covering the box?

It's basically the flip side of these questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929557/tensorflow-cnn-training-images-are-all-different-sizes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907598/how-to-train-images-when-they-have-different-size

Comment: The question isn't clear. Could you try to explain it in a clearer fashion?

Comment: @Royi: If you are training a neural net for a bunch of images of different size, and you have to put them all in a same-size enclosing box for input to the neural net, what's the best way to fill the background, if at all, where the inserted image is not covering the box?

Comment: This is a much clearer explanation. You should rewrite the question in that spirit and I will be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the appropriate answer in [this patch of code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py) from Google Tensorflow for Poets 2.  It does what I needed to do at the moment it needed to get done.  The variables **input_height** and **input_width** are the destination sizes, not the source sizes:

```
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0)
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
```